# Design problems writing JSON interpreter

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

I decided to write a json interpreter in c++ for practice. Ideally I want to be able to set it up in a treelike container of maps, vectors and the relevant value types so that i can access in the way the json is actually structured. E.g. given the following JSON example (from json.org):

```
JSON
{
"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}


C++
jsonobject["menu"]["id"] // returns std::string "file"
jsonobject["menu"]["popup"]["menuitem"] // returns std::vector of std::maps
jsonobject["menu"]["popup"]["menuitem"][0]["value"] // returns std::string "New"
```

In the above example, my first problem arised from having mixed types inside containers. For example, in the above json "menu" would be a std::map, but I cannot have the keys "id" and "popup" since one returns a string and the other a vector.

To get around this issue, I decided that I'd create wrapper template class that inherits from a typeless base class. Assuming this would give polymorphic access to the values. The problem is I can't. Here's some code to show what I have so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class NodeBase {};

template <typename T>
class Node : public BaseNode {};

typedef std::map<std::string, BaseNode*> JSONObject;
template <>
class Node<JSONObject> : public BaseNode {
  public:
    JSONObject value;
    BaseNode* operator[](const std::string key){(value.find(key) != value.end) ? return value[key] : return nullptr}
};

typedef std::vector<BaseNode*> JSONArray;
template <>
class Node<JSONArray> : public BaseNode {
  public:
    JSONArray value;
    BaseNode* operator[](const uint index) {(index < value.size()) ? return value[index] : return nullptr}
};

template <typename T>
class Node : public BaseNode {
  public:
    T value;
};

class RootNode {
  Node<JSONObject> value;
};

int main(void) {
  RootNode root;
  root.insert(std::pair<std::string, BaseNode*>("menu", new Node<JSONObject>)
  // problem!
  // cannot use following code, because BaseNode* does not have access to value :'<
  root["menu"].insert(..)
}
```

So I guess my question is, how do I make this work? Am I on the right path but unable to see the solution from inexperience, or is this design simply incompatible with C++?

Comment: Check out [Boost Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: @Joachim I noticed boost be suggested in a few google searches about accessing unknown variable types from base->derived. And in the end I probably will. I'm just trying to solve problems on my own, perhaps not ideally or how you would in a real world solution, but to see what issues arise from my designs and if they are actually valid/possible. That way in the future, I'll have a good idea of what I can and cannot do. Thanks the for the advise though!

Comment: [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) would be a better fit here than Boost.Any. Indeed, Variant even comes with a wrapper making recursive types possible, as is frequently needed when representing hierarchical data such as XML or JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting class, but i recently used boost::property_three to parse json and happy i avoided reinventing wheel xD Your library may work as lightweight parser so i interested in this research.

I think this design is not very good, cus people who use library may not know what certain value contain: hash or array. This can lead to overloading with `dynamic_cast` which is relatively heavy operation. As result, your library loses its "lightweight" property.

I suggest to use one object type notation, like all `Get` methods return `Node*`, but `Node*` can answer questions `isArray()`, `isHash()` without heavy operations like dynamic casts.

Next, `Node<JSONObject>` and `Node<JSONArray>` should have same interface inherited from `BaseNode`: `BaseNode* operator[](const std::string key)`, but `Node<JSONArray>` is able to receive `int` key by `operator[]` overloading. This minifies API and allows user use `int` indexes if he know it is array. But its not a panacea, you should do what called "library  designing".

Globally, i recommend not to write code right now. Write some class hierarchy schemas, write some use cases; look how these use cases can fit into schema. Generally writing such librarys in not a trivial task and "design" mistakes may make your library unusable in future. So, choose wise=) Goodluck!

Comment: Yeah, Boost sounds good. I'm really just doing it for the sake of practice and experience. Thanks for the advise though, I'll give my design a rethink.